# Reveal.js. How to temporarily disable the reveal property so that I can add other thing for example like telestration on top of the window

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

I created a Canvas on top of the reveal and have realized the basic drawing functionality on Canvas in test code.

However, when I show the canvas and do drawing stuff with my touch screen, it captures drawing function and swiping the sections at the same time.

Are there default settings that I can change to temporarily disable the swiping?

Comment: Can you  show us your code ?

Comment: Thanks for checking! Solved.See comments below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for thinking or answering this questions.

It turns out that there is no switch function in reveal.js that can turn the slide function temporarily off or not.

However, to implement the drawing functionality, there is a function called

```
 d3.event.stopPropagation();
```

or

```
 event.stopPropagation();
```

which can stop the swipe or dragging action on canvas/d3 from penetrating into the reveal.js swipe event.